# Fractional Inequality $|\frac{2}{x-4}| > 1$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I have tried like this
$|\frac{2}{x-4}| > 1 \quad$
$\frac{2}{x-4} > 1$   Or.   $\frac{2}{x-4} < -1$;
$x-4 < 2$.                   Or.   $4-x < 2$;
$x>6$.                       Or      $x>2$;
 But my text book says it is wrong and the correct answer is 
$(2,4) \cup (4,6)$

Comment: How did you go from $\frac{2}{x-4}\gt 1$ to $x-4\gt 2$ ?

Comment: Oops I corrected it

Comment: Still doesn't look right. Are you sure you're not multiplying by a `negative` number?

Comment: Because inequality doesn't remain the same when you multiply both sides by a `negative` number

Comment: Would you like to accept an answer, Mathematical?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For $x\neq 4$ we get
$$2>|x-4|$$
so we have to solve $2>x-4$ for $x>4$ or
$2>-x+4$ for $x<4$.
The solution is given by $$2<x<4$$ or $$4<x<6$$

Answer (score 1):

We obtain $x\neq4$ and $$|x-4|<2$$ or
$$-2<x-4<2$$ or
$$2<x<6,$$ which with $x\neq4$ gives:
$$(2,4)\cup(4,6).$$

Comment: To not to have zero in remainder you did that.But you didn't consider the case where it is less than zero isn't or otherwise I was mistaken somewherw

Comment: @Mathematical Curiosity I solved your problem without cases. I used a definition of $|\cdot|$ and from here we see that $|x|<a$ it's $-a<x<a.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Take the reciprocals of both sides. The inequation becomes, taking into account its domain of validity,
$$\biggl|\frac{x-4}2\biggr|<1\iff |x-4|<2\quad\textbf{ and }\quad x\ne 4$$
and interpret this inequality in terms of distance.

Comment: Oh i get it.Others also shown solution but I understand yours the best.Thank all of you

Answer (score 0):

Since $|2/x-4|> 1$, so $|(x-4)/2| <1$ 
This gives $$-2< x-4 <2$$ and hence $2<x < 6$ 
But since $x\neq 4$ so $x \in (2,4) \cup (4,6)$

Answer (score 0):

$x \not = 4;$

$\left | \dfrac{2}{4-x} \right |$ implies

1)$ \dfrac{2}{x-4} >1$, or

2) $\dfrac{2}{x-4}<-1$;

1) $x >4$ (why?) , and

$2 >x-4$, or $6 >x$,

Hence $x \in (4,6)$.

2) $x< 4$ (why?), and

$2 >(4-x)$, or $x>2$.

Hence $x \in (2,4)$.

Finally $x \in (2,4)\cup (4,6)$.